# python multiprocessing pool not work when we run many tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Example: I have a CPU with 2 threads so I have 2 workers with this code.

```
tasks = ['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt', '4.txt', '5.txt']

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
pool.map(myfunc, tasks, chunksize=1)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

If I run this program it will process '1.txt' and '2.txt' first and then when one of them done the job it will start next file. That mean at a time it process only 2 files, right?

But I found the problem when I run with many many files. (maybe more than 100+ files). Program will not wait until one of 2 workers done the job but it will assign job to worker 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and so on.

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you everyone in advance.

P.S. I use Python 3.6.

Comment: Can you give us a [mcve] and/or explain the problem better?

Comment: There shouldn't be more than 2 workers if you have two cores. If you're worried about that, you can check it, or just explicitly pass `2` to force it.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the number of worker processes in the pool passing it as an argument to `multiprocessing.Pool()`.

Example:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def myfunc(t):
    print("{} starts".format(t))
    time.sleep(1)
    print("{} ends".format(t))

tasks = ['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt', '4.txt', '5.txt']

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
pool.map(myfunc, tasks, chunksize=1)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

which on my machine outputs

```
1.txt starts
2.txt starts
1.txt ends
3.txt starts
2.txt ends
4.txt starts
3.txt ends
5.txt starts
4.txt ends
5.txt ends
```

while not specifying the number of worker processes what I get is:

```
1.txt starts
2.txt starts
3.txt starts
4.txt starts
3.txt ends
1.txt ends
2.txt ends
4.txt ends
5.txt starts
5.txt ends
```